# Node.js get user input without printing a newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

When using `readline.question()`, you always get a newline at the end of the user input. How can you remove that newline or not output it from the beginning?

For example, consider the following code:

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: true
});
rl.question("Question: ", line => {
    console.log("?");
});
```

Expected:

```
Question: [User question]?
```

Actual:

```
Question: [User question]
?
```

This asks the user for some text, and adds a `?` mark to the end of the user input. But the `?` mark is at the next line.

Comment: just a guess this might work for what you want. 

rl.question(""+"?", line => {
   
});

Comment: @FahadNisar I want to add the `?` mark after the user input instead of inside the question directly, so that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: @Bill could you please update the question with an example of both the current output and the expected output?

Comment: @deedub OK, I have updated the question to include that

Answer (score 1):

The question mark should be part of the string in the first parameter of `rl.question()`. Example from [Readline docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html):

```
rl.question('What is your favorite food? ', (answer) => {
  console.log(`Oh, so your favorite food is ${answer}`);
});
```

If you have a variable that you want to use, that doesn't have a `?` symbol included, you could do:

```
rl.question(thisVar + '?', line => {
    // do whatever
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I probably didn't fully explain the problem. I want to add the `?` mark after the user input instead of inside the question directly. I've edited the original post to clarify this.